# Быстрая работа с 3млн записями

Tags: файлы, php, mysql

В общем у меня есть 3млн сайтов и ещё 2 изменяющихся у них св-ва, к примеру число человек и кол-во ботов. Т.е. 3 млн записей подобного рода: test.ru (сайт) 527 (кол-во человек) 987 (кол-во ботов)
Каким способом быстрее сделать: mysql базу данных организовать для этих записей, или всё в файл записывать? Я бы работал с файлом но нужно сравнивать предидущее значение с текущим, поэтому с файлами неудобно( Т.к. придётся по всему файлу искать нужную запись, посоветуйте что-нибудь, пож-та.

Comment: Я делал нечто подобное создавая по таблице для каждого дня

Comment: В каком смысле для каждого дня?

Comment: Чтобы сравнивать "предыдущее значение с текущим"... для каждого дня своя таблица, в которой значения в этот день

Comment: Ну, впринципе, да, наверно с помощью файлов буду делать. Т.к. особых поисковых, сортировочных действий не буду производить, спасибо.